# C++ Builder XE2 - linking resource with component

Tags: embedded-resource, custom-component, c++builder-xe2

I have derived my own component based on class *TCustomControl*. I need to embedd into component bitmap resource stored in .png format. I added to project file *resources.rc* with this content:

```
AP_LOGO RCDATA .\AP_logo_RGB_transparent.png
```

Compilation was successfull. Component is statically linked to project. When I run the application it throws following error when trying to access embedded resource:

```
Project raised exception class EResNotFound with message 'Resource AP_LOGO not found'.
```

The following lines in source code access bitmap resource:

```
  Graphics::TBitmap *bmp = new Graphics::TBitmap();
  HINST handle = FindClassHInstance(__classid(TVctDiag2));
  bmp->LoadFromResourceName(handle, L"AP_LOGO"); // <----- exception apppers there
```

When I open executable with resource editor there isnt any resource named 'AP_LOGO'. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the `TBitmap::LoadFromResource...()` methods look for `BITMAP` resources only, but you have defined an `RCDATA` resource instead.  If you don't change your resource type then you will have to use `TResourceStream` instead, eg:

```
HINST handle = FindClassHInstance(__classid(TVctDiag2));
TResourceStream *strm = new TResourceStream(handle, L"AP_LOGO", RT_RCDATA);
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp = new Graphics::TBitmap();
bmp->LoadFromStream(strm);
delete strm;
```

With that saif, you cannot load a PNG resource into a `TBitmap` to begin with.  If you must use a PNG resource then you have to use a PNG class instead, like `TPngImage`.

Comment: Resource 'AP_LOGO' not found.

Comment: Then your resource is not actually being compiled into your component package. Are you sure you added the .rc file to the project? Have you tried using the IDE's own built-in Resource Manager instead of using an .rc file?

Comment: When i compile component as dynamically linked library .bpl, i can see AP_LOGO resource in it. When I link component statically, AP_LOGO resource is not linked to executable. As for built-in Resource Manager - no I haven't.

Comment: Then your resource is not asscoated with your package correctly.  If done correctly, a statically linked package has the same resources as a dynamically linked package. That is why `FindClassHInstace()` is useful for finding component resources.